# Write each row of Pyspark dataframe into a new text file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with over 50k rows but only 2 columns - `ID` and `Content`. I want to iterate through each row and create a text file with the name from the `ID` field and the contents from the `Content` field. For example, for the following dataframe I want to create two files `A1234.txt` and `B5678.txt` containing the contents of the first and second row respectively.

```py
data = [
    ("A1234", "Hello World.\n These are the contents of the first text file."),
    ("B5678", "These are the contents of the second text file."),
]
columns = ["ID", "Content"]
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
display(df_test)
```

I understand that maybe `dbutils.fs.put` utility can be used - but I don't know to iterate and apply this to the rows. Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: spark dataframe does not allow you to iterate over rows easily, but it is easy in pandas. if memory is not an issue here, have you tried converting the spark dataframe to pandas dataframe and iterate over rows?

Comment: i disagree with the folks marking this as duplicate. the tagged question does not help the OP as OP needs the contents of the row as file name whereas the tagged question just saves all contents in different text file with spark internal nomenclature.

Comment: @samkart Thank you for understanding that this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate just because parts of it overlap with the other question. I did try the Pandas option earlier, but for some reason, I couldn't get to work - maybe I was doing something wrong. Though I've now used the solution provided by Andrea, and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for row in df_test.collect():
  with open("your_path/" + row[0] + ".txt", "w") as filehandle:
    filehandle.write(row[1])
```

Comment: from PySpark docs -> "DataFrame.collect() collects the distributed data to the driver side as the local data in Python. Note that this can throw an out-of-memory error when the dataset is too large to fit in the driver side because it collects all the data from executors to the driver side."